# How to make an image link to the post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

My posts have an image in them. They are shown in the homepage of my site. Each post has a picture, a description about the post, and a "more" button which takes the user to the full article.

My issue is that I want to make the image link to the full post. I want the image to function as the "more" button.

I have tried using jQuery, wrap() function, linking the image in the article itself, nothing has worked out so far.

The code for the image is just:

```
<img src="random.jpg" class="YTimgs">
```

Does anybody know how I can get this to work? I have been working on this issue and have not found the correct solution. I hope someone helps me out.

Comment: I don't know your full html but you can write $('img').click(function(){ var moreLink = //GetMoreButton.trigger('click');})

Comment: why not wrap img inside <a href="link_to_post"> <img src="random.jpg" class="YTimgs"> </a> directly in layout?

Comment: Wrap the image in `a` tags with the corresponding `href`? Or do you mean something else? This is pretty basic.

Comment: I can use the <a> tag with the link to make it work. However, this would mean that I have to go to all the thousands of posts that I have created and editing them manually.

Comment: What I want is a piece of code that can use the link from the "More" button and add it to the link of the image. You can see my site www.chordzone.org to get a clearer view.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your images have class *YTimg*, others have *YTimgs* ... give it only one class:

```
$(document).on("click", "img.YTimgs", function(){
    $(this).closest("div.post").find(".jump-link").find("a").trigger("click");
});
```

And this should do the tricky

Comment: Can you tell me the code to find the title link in the post? Please check www.chordzone.org. Each post has a title, I would like to click on the image in the post, which would take me to the full post. For that I need the link of the post. I hope you understood my question.

Comment: I've added the link to my site, still nothing seems to work. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure.. do you have the last version of jquery?

Comment: I'm using <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/> in my script. I don't know if that is the latest version. Your code sounds like it could fix my problem. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5md7p9L7/7/

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/>
<a class="link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">The picture and this text are both links to the same page :)</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var link =$(this).next().attr('href');
    window.open(link);   
});
```

Comment: such question and such answer on stackoverflow? seriously?)

Comment: I've tried your code on my site, it doesn't work. I'm not getting any errors either. What could be wrong?